# Pandora won't delete stations that I've already deleted

Tags: pandora

I have a station that I have tried deleting multiple times, but when I go back on Pandora the next time, it shows up like I've never deleted it. How do I fix this? I don't want to keep having to delete it every time I want to use Pandora.